# Remove &amp;nbsp; from a html string saved in NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString* test = @"<b> Terms and Conditions</b><br />
- No  smoking(by law) <br />
 &amp;nbsp; No chewing pan(by law)<br />"
[test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;nbsp;" withString:@"s"];
```

I tried to remove that `"&amp;nbsp;"` but it fails to do so? Any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`test` is an immutable string and you are ignoring the result when you do the replacement. Try this:

```
test = [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;nbsp;" withString:@"s"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This method doesn't change the string to which you send the message, but rather returns a new string.

```
NSString *newStr = [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;nbsp;"
                                                   withString:@"s"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to manipulate the string with the following unit test:

```
- (void) testStringManipulation {
    NSString* test = @"<b> Terms and Conditions</b><br />   - No  smoking(by law) <br /> &amp;nbsp; No chewing pan(by law)<br />";
    NSString* expected = @"<b> Terms and Conditions</b><br />   - No  smoking(by law) <br /> s No chewing pan(by law)<br />";
    NSString *result = [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;nbsp;" withString:@"s"];
    STAssertTrue([expected isEqualToString:result], @"Should be true");
}
```

This passes in my IDE.
I'm using OCUnit.

Did you put the `[test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString...` in a new variable?
This method does not mutate the object, but returns a new string instance.

Answer (score 0):

You might just try replacing &nbsp; with &#160 instead and see how that compiles that way.